# How to get the first row ever recorded in a table without sorting in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, sorting

Say you have a table with n rows, what is the most efficient way to get the first row ever recorded on that table without sorting?

This is guaranteed to work, but becomes slower as the number of records increases:

```
SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1;
```

UPDATE:

This is even better in case there are multiple records with the same `created_at` value, but still needs sorting:

```
SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Imagine a ledger book with 1 million pages and 1 billion lines of records, to get the first ever record, you'd simply turn to the first page and get the one on the top most, right? Regardless of the size of the ledger, you should get the first ever record with the same efficiency. I was hoping I could do the same in MySQL without doing any kind of sorting or ordering. For research purposes. I mean, why not? Why can't MySQL? Is it impossible by design?

This is possible in typical array structures in programming:

`array = [1,2,3,4,5]`

The first element is in `array[0]`, the second in `array[1]` and so on. There is no sorting necessary. The last element is `array[array_count(array)-1]`.

Comment: This is probably the fastest and easiest way to do this.  Side question: What do you want to happen if two records have the same timestamp?

Comment: You could use a subquery with `MAX()`, but this would also involve a process similar to sorting.

Comment: use a primary key with autoincrement, select id = 1, since the primary key is indexed it doesn't have to sort the entire table

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen if you create an index on the column that issue would be resolved though

Comment: This is the last row ever recorded.

Comment: @GillesLesire's suggestion of using the auto incremented id would still need to sort the least ids because we won't know which record has the least id. Say we have records with ids of 3,4,5 and 8, it's not safe to say that the first record has the id of 1 because it's already gone. It's not 2 either. Because we don't know, we would need to sort the records by their ids.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, for this example, in case multiple records have the same created_at value, I'd simply get the first one of them. But for this example, I'd like to assume a collision would not happen.

Comment: @doncadavona I gave an answer below which may help you.

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen!

Comment: @doncadavona Yes but when you search on an indexed column it will only sort the index, not the entire data table. That is the least sorting possible for this operation. Without sorting as the question poses is impossible. If the data might get removed, simply select where id = MIN(id)

Comment: Thanks guys for all your comments. This is turning out to be an impossible operation since MySQL still needs to do sorting. My idea was that MySQL should be able to do it by simply getting the first record on the table by getting whichever is in the bottom of the record stack, that is if MySQL stores records in a stack structure (first-in last-out). I'd need to look into why is that.

Comment: "The first record" is a generally uninteresting record.  "Record with value of X for field Y" is interesting, and what databases are designed to do.

Answer (score 2):

I can offer the following two queries to find the most recent record:

```
SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1
```

and

```
SELECT *
FROM posts
WHERE created_at = (SELECT MAX(created_at) FROM posts
```

Both queries would suffer from performance degredation as the table gets larger, because the sorting operation needed to find the most recent created date would take more time.

But in both cases, adding the following index should improve the performance of the query:

```
ALTER TABLE posts ADD INDEX created_idx (created_at)
```

MySQL can use an index both in the `ORDER BY` clause and when finding the max.  See the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html) for more information.

Comment: Thank you @tim, this is a really good solution for the scenario. But I am hoping there is some way, maybe a super low level way it can be done in MySQL's core. I may not be able to get that, but I'd like to keep this question unanswered until the true answer is found. Maybe some core developer would confirm that it's impossible sometime in the future.

Comment: @doncadavona Well something just popped into my head as matter of fact.  If you really want to record the first row, you could setup a trigger which would duplicate the first inserted record assuming the target table be completely empty.

Comment: That would mean we'd need to keep track on each record, it will double our records of 1 billion into 2 billion. Assuming we keep record of each record's storage sequence in the database. Also, the entire table would have to be reindexed each time a record is added and removed. It would be too expensive. This is actually not just about the first record, the first record would just be our guide in the sequence of the entire table. Much like when we have an array of a=[1,2,3,4,5], the first record would be a[0]. The second is a[1], and so fort. There is no sorting or anything.

Comment: Do you want a bounty or something?

Comment: No, not this time. I'm just curious and wondered if it had a quick/obvious answer before. But thanks for your comments and answer regardless!